# Retry not happening in Do Until loop

Tags: azure-logic-apps

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9pTk.png)Attached screenshot show the Do Until loop in design mode & at execution mode .Please let me know why the loop is not executing until value = Succeeded.[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSwu4.png)[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4b7S.png)

Comment: What's your until action expression?

Comment: @equals(actions('Get_Execution_Summary_status').Status, 'Succeeded')

Comment: From your image it should continue to execute until status equals succeeded. Are you sure your loop is not executing?

Comment: Yes George . Please find the screen schot attached where the loop got executed only once , even when the value = executing .

Comment: @GeorgeChen: Please find the options below which I tried .

Comment: Case 1: actions('Get_Execution_Summary_status').Status
     Result :No looping 
Case 2: actions('Get_Execution_Summary_Status').outputs 
     Result :Looped untill the timeout period 
Case 3 : @equals(actions('Get_Execution_Summary_Status')['OutputParameters']['value'], 'Succeeded')
     Result : cannot be evaluated because property 'OutputParameters' doesn't exist 
case 4: actions('Get_Execution_Summary_Status')['value']
     Result:cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist.

Comment: case 5: actions('Get_Execution_Summary_Status')['status']  
     Result:No looping 
Case 6 : actions('Get_Execution_Summary_Status')['outputs'] 
     Result:Looped untill the timeout period

Answer (score 0):

This expression inside the until loop condtion worked @equals(outputs('Get_Execution_Summary_Status')['body']?['value'], 'Succeeded')